# adding a field causes the entire report to duplicate itself on another page

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

[image]

As the report is now everything works fine, prints on 1 page. When I add a field next to USER_T6, USER_T7, or USER_T8 it will duplicate the entire report on a second page and print that TEST EQUIPMENT USED portion at the end of the second page. If I add the field to all 3 USER_T fields I'll have something like 10 pages of duplicates then finally that data on the last page. This only occurs when I add another field next to one of those USER_T lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a bad join with another table causing null fields for every row thus duplicating the data for each null value per row.